# How can i use spring jpa to perform a thread safe "update XXX set a = a + 1" statement?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

Of course,we can do this job like:

```
User old = userRepository.findOne("xxx@gmail.com");
old.setFollwersNumber(old.getFollwersNumber() + 1);
userRepository.save(old);
```

but it's not thread safe, isn't it?

Comment: What do you mean by not safe?

Comment: And that wouldn't be safe because?

Comment: I mean it's not thread safe.

Comment: You are confusing thread safety with transactions. They are not the same concepts. The above code is thread safe, as it deals solely with local variables.

Comment: @TomG `userRepository` is storage, not just local variable and this code modify object in storage in not thread-safe way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [lock](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#locking) your object on query, [available lock modes](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/LockModeType.html)

Answer (score 0):

Are you worried abut two people following the same user at the same time and then this number will not be correct?

Instead of updating the User object to track the number of followers, why don't you write a query that would query the number of followers? Do you have a following table or something that could be queried?  This would keep the two from getting out of sync.

There are multiple options for then caching/expiring this data in your application for performance.